# tstream is buffer overflow proof?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, buffer-overflow, tstream

TStream is an abstract class.

However about its implementations, are they buffer overflow proof?

If I'm fetching a stream from the internet, from a source that is not me, how do I verify that it is not corrupted and cause buffer overflow?

Lets say that the stream is an xml file.

edit:
all the answers indicate you need to check for buffer overflow.
could you demonstrate how to check a buffer overflow on an input file, where we know that a stream could be infinite by its definition?

Comment: "we know that a stream could be infinite by its definition" - that's irrelevant.  With a Delphi stream, you don't have to read into memory any more of it than you want, as the answers explained.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`TStream` and its various RTL descendents do not have any bugs that result in buffer overruns, to the best of my knowledge.

However, your code using Delphi streams could easily overrun a buffer.

Comment: so you say that a bug is not to your knowledge, however possible? (the second part was not clear for me).

Comment: Of course it is possible that there are bufs in the RTL. I'd look at your code first though. You are more likely to find errors there. I don't mean that in a personal way. I apply the same philosophy to code I write.

Comment: could you provide a piece of code that is robast or a buffer overflowable code? any of the two would answer the question.

Comment: i dont get how the delphi stream could be buffered overflowed. i ask if you could please, add a code that demonstrate safty in TSreams, for the simple case we could talk about TMemoryStream.

Comment: If you use a stream properly then you won't overflow any buffers.

Answer (score 5):

`TStream` reads into whatever buffer the caller supplies.  It is the caller's responsibility to make sure the supplied buffer and its size are valid.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you should depend on the `Size` property of the presented stream to set the size of your own buffer before filling it. The only reason for that `Size` property not delivering the real size would be a wrong implementation of either `Seek` methods. Unless that method determines the size of the stream on weird boundary assumptions, a single test should rule out any problems.

In any case, whether the stream contains corrupted data or not, it should néver run into a buffer overflow on your side if you just not download more than the size of your own buffer.

You could also request the type of the presented stream and verify if it is a standard Delphi stream. If so, then you need not be worried.

Comment: lets say it is a standard Delphi stream.

Answer (score 1):

No, TStream descendants are not 'overflow proof'. But if you follow the advice of Remy and NGLN, you will write code that is as safe as possible with Delphi streams.

If you are afraid of something malicious, handle it within a try/except and/or try/finally block and clean up any potential damage.

Correct usage of 'try' is the key to **SAFE** Delphi programming - there are no silver bullets. That is the price you pay when you use a compiled language than allows you to get 'close to the metal'.

Comment: heres a silver bullet, the c library of safe, which protects the buffer and has manual to read about how to protect yourself.

Comment: So you could write your routine in C and if you need it in a Delphi app, it's not hard to create a Delphi wrapper for it. But AFIK there is 'no such animal' in the out-of-box Delphi, although there may be 3rd party stuff out there.